# While migrating code from Tensorflow 1 to Tensorflow 2, how do I deal with the attribute error: 'Adam' object has no attribute 'compute_gradient'?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm working with Tensorflow and am using code which has been implemented for Tensorflow 1 (https://github.com/openai/maddpg/blob/master/maddpg/common/tf_util.py). While migrating code to tensorflow 2, I'm able to make most of the changes using the literature provided online. However, I'm not able to find a suitable alternative to line 145:

```
gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(objective, var_list=var_list)
```

Which throws an error

```
Attribute Error: 'Adam' object has no attribute 'compute_gradient'
```

Since this function no longer exists, what are the possible alternatives I can use? I have read that it is possible to use the following function instead:

```
gradients = optimizer.get_gradients(objective, var_list)
```

This throws a value error

```
ValueError: Variable <tf.Variable 'agent_0/q_func/fully_connected/weights:0' shape=(9, 64) 
dtype=float32> has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a 
gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, 
K.round, K.eval.
```

```
Versions:
tensorflow              2.4.1
tensorflow-estimator    2.4.0
```

Comment: hi, in TensorFlow 2.x you can use GradientTap install of using these method instead of the method you have used. because this method basically uses in TensorFlow 1.x and both TensorFlow versions in some issue have conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it using `tf.GradientTape`. Something like this:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y_pred = my_obj_function(w, b, x)
    loss = my_loss(y_pred, y)

dw, db = tape.gradient(loss, [w, b])
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip([dw, db], [w, b]))
```

So the gradient is inside the tape, as this object was watching the variables (`w` and `b`) and the gradient of the loss function with regard to these variables. Then you can pass the variables and their gradients to the optimizer to perform an iteration of optimization.
The objective function and loss function for the above example:

```
def my_loss(y_pred, y_true):
    return tf.abs(y_pred - y_true)


def my_obj_function(w, b, x):
    return w * x + b
```

### Update

As I mentioned in my comment, make sure all elements inside the var lists are `TF variables`. if some of them are not, covert them simply by using:

```
var_list = [tf.variable(var) for var in var_list]
```

Then you would be able to calculate the gradient as fallow:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    cost = objective(target, the_inputs)
gradients = tape.gradient(cost, var_list)
```

`the_inputs` are the necessary values to calculate the `cost` using `objective` function. the `tape` only watches the values that are defined as `TF variables` and only can calculate the gradients for them. And having the gradients, you can simply use the optimizer to reduce the cost in this iteration:

```
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, var_list))
```

Comment: The code that I have provided in the link is using a list of variables and at least some of the objects returned from tape.gradient are non-iterable NoneType objects. Could you provide an example of how it should be restructured for this code?

Comment: @Maximillius make sure the variables you're passing to gradients are TF variable and not TP constant or any other type. you can check it by simply printing out the variables.

Answer (score 0):

`tf.GradientTape` will work. Look here:

```
lst_var = [tf.variable(var) for var in var_list]
```

Now you can calculate it:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tp:
    cost = objective(target, inputs)
    gradients = tp.gradient(cost, lst_var)
```